# Access to a different Controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I want to access to my TestControler in DefaultController. So I've create a new instance, but the container is null. If I want to call a method, symfony throws a FatalErrorException:

> Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

**DefaultController:**

```
/**
 * DefaultController.
 *
 */
class DefaultControllerextends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $contrTest = new TestController();
        var_dump($contrTest);           
    }
```

**var_dump result:**

> object(test\testBundle\Controller\TestController)#283 (1) {
>   ["container":protected]=>   NULL }

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using other controllers inside a controller is a sign of bad architecture. Usually, it means you have to split the controller into a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), which you can use everywhere, and a controller.

For instance, when you have a controller which has a `parseAction` which parses a file and you need to use that in another controller too, you must create a `acme_demo.parser.the_file_type` service (give it which name you want) and use that in both controllers:

```
// ...
class FirstController extends Controller
{
    public function xxxAction()
    {
        $parser = $this->get('acme_demo.parser.the_file_type');

        $data = $parser->parse(...);
    }
}

// ...
class SecondController extends Controller
{
    public function yyyAction()
    {
        $parser = $this->get('acme_demo.parser.the_file_type');

        $data = $parser->parse(...);
    }
}
```